# Manipulate the href attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few URLs and would like to add a slash (/) before them.

This is how they look in my HTML:

```
<li class="link">
    <a href="products/">Products</a>
</li>
<li class="link">
    <a href="team/">Team</a>
</li>
<li class="link">
    <a href="contact/">Contact</a>
</li>
```

How can I manipulate the link in the `href` attribute, so it looks e.g. like this: `/products/` ?

The solution must work on IE 10!

Comment: can you show what you've tried?

Comment: You could probably have googled this before asking.

Comment: @MichaelZhang then why would you answer it instead of finding the dupe?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to do it like following.

```js
$('.link a').attr('href', function(){
    return '/' + $(this).attr('href');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="link">
        <a href="products/">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        <a href="team/">Team</a>
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        <a href="contact/">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this is not working on Internet Explorer 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attr()` to change links

```js
$('li.link a').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', '/' + $(this).attr('href'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="link">
  <a href="products/">Products</a>
</li>
<li class="link">
  <a href="team/">Team</a>
</li>
<li class="link">
  <a href="contact/">Contact</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(element).attr("href", "http://example.com")` to change the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this

```
var name = "/" + $('.link').children().attr('href');
$('.link').children().attr('href',name);
```

Checkout the jquery .attr() documentation
http://api.jquery.com/attr/